# The thickness of the hair is different from what it looks like in real life

Tags: modeling, particles, hair, filmic-blender

As shown in the image, I set the Diameter Root value to 0.01m and the Diameter Scale value to 0.01.
Thus, the thickness of the hair is 0.1 mm, which is a value thicker than real hair.

The amount of hair is set to about 160,000 strands, which is also more than in reality.

However, when I check it in the render view, it is clear that the hair is thinner than in reality.
What could be the cause?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to apply real-world size. Just try to increase the diameter size, so that you can get the results you expect.